# What is the best way to transfer large files using aws s3 cp command of awscli

Tags: multithreading, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am transferring around 150 files each 1 gb to s3 using aws s3 cp command in a loop which takes around 20 sec/file, so would be 50 mins. If i put all the files in directory it takes upto 40 mins if i use folder copy with --recursive which is Multithread. I tried to change the s3 config by specifying the concurrent req to 20 , increased bandwidth, but its almost same time. What is the best way to reduce the time.

Comment: Consider https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-upload-large-files/

Comment: You could use a bandwidth calculator to determine the maximum potential throughput from your Internet connection. The main limiting factors will be bandwidth, overhead (moreso for small files) and concurrency.